# python re match digits or digits followed by characters

Tags: python, regex

How would I match the following strings:

```
str1 = "he will be 60 years old today"
str2 = "she turns 79yo today this afternoon"
```

I want to match strings that contain a digit or digit immediately followed by characters (no whitespace separated).

Comment: Could you post the expected output?

Comment: Check for space just before the number: /\b\d+/ ... _https://regex101.com/r/eS9pR4/2_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex to match those words:

```
\b\d+\w*\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dT5gW8/7)

**Code:**

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'\b\d+\w*\b')
test_str = u"he will be 60 years old today\nshe turns 79yo today this afternoon"

print re.findall(p, test_str)
```

**Output:**

```
[u'60', u'79yo']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `[0-9]\w+`

```
>>> re.findall('[0-9]\w+', 'hello my friend kilojoules 99how are you?')
['99how']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generator expression within `any()` :

```
any(i.isdigit() or i[0].isdigit() for i in my_str.split())
```

Demo :

```
>>> str1 = "he will be 60 years old today"
>>> str2 = "she turns 79yo today this afternoon"
>>> str3 = "he will be5  ye48ars old today"
>>> any(i.isdigit() or i[0].isdigit() for i in str1.split())
True
>>> any(i.isdigit() or i[0].isdigit() for i in str2.split())
True
>>> any(i.isdigit() or i[0].isdigit() for i in str3.split())
False
```